# Use sln in Fabric

Tags: database, ssis, etl, microsoft-fabric

Are sln files usable in Fabric?
I have a project that I created in SSIS, and I'm attempting to migrate it to Fabric to transfer all of my work.
Thank you in advance.

I have a project that I created in SSIS, and I'm attempting to migrate it to Fabric to transfer all of my work.

I want to continue my SSIS project in Microsoft Fabric, and I want to use it as it is. Simply put, I am not familiar with the Workspace in Microsoft Fabric, and I would like to know if this is possible.

Comment: To clarify: You wrote SSIS packages and are attempting to migrate them to which Fabric: the python SSH library, google-fabric,  fabricjs, hyperledger-fabric, minecraft-fabric?

Comment: Fabric isn't the replacement of SSIS. That was Power BI, which replaced SSIS *and* SSAS *and* SSRS. Fabric is the evolution/replacement of Power BI. SSIS specifically was replaced by Azure Data Factory, Power Query and other services used to load data into Power BI

Comment: Migrating your work actually means rewriting it to load local data into Power BI on Azure, or whatever name it has now.

Comment: SSIS is not supported in Fabric, you need to move it to pipelines (basically Data Factory). This is the wrong tag, it should be [microsoft-fabric] (updated in the edit)